# Using Interceptors to customize header in Retrofit calls

Tags: android, retrofit2, interceptor

I am trying to use an Interceptor  to add a header when using Retrofit. I think I have created my Interceptor in the right way but I don't know what should I do to call it and connect it with my GET Retrofit method.

This is my Interceptor:

```
public class HeaderInterceptor
            implements Interceptor {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain)
                throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();
            request = request.newBuilder()
                    .addHeader(Constants.VersionHeader.NAME, Constants.VersionHeader.VALUE)
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
                    .addHeader("Origin","MY URL")
                    .build();
            Response response = chain.proceed(request);
            return response;
        }
    }
```

And this is my interface:

```
public interface CategoryService {

    @GET("/v3/projects/{projectId}/categories/")
    Call<ArrayList<Category2>> getProjectCategories(@Path("projectId") String projectId);
}
```

I also have this client which I don't know if I should use it anymore considering that I am using an Interceptor:

```
public class CategoryClient {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "MY URL";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;


    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

So I have this GET method getProjectCategories, where I pass the projectID and it returns the contents. What I want to know is how can I call the method using the Interceptor and be able to get the results from the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my problem by creating a method called SendNetworkRequest sending the projectId as a parameter, and inside this class I created my OkHttpClient, my Interceptor and my retrofit builder to handle everything that i needed.

```
private void SendNetworkRequest(String projectID) {

        OkHttpClient.Builder okhttpBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

        okhttpBuilder.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {

                Request request = chain.request();

                Request.Builder newRequest = request.newBuilder().header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

                return chain.proceed(newRequest.build());
            }
        });

        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("MY URL")
                .client(okhttpBuilder.build())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

        Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

        CategoryService category = retrofit.create(CategoryService.class);
        Call<ArrayList<Category2>> call = category.getProjectCategories(projectID, token);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<Category2>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<Category2>> call, Response<ArrayList<Category2>> response) {

                listCategories = response.body();
                listCategories.remove(response.body().size() - 1);
                if (response.body().size() > 0){
                    add_category_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    layout_bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    message_body.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    message_title.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    edit_image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    adapter2 = new CategoryAdapter2(getApplicationContext(), listCategories);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter2);
                    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<Category2>> call, Throwable t) {
                // Log error here since request failed
                Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
            }
        });
    }
```